# loess warnings errors in geom_smooth in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, smoothing

Why does the following code successfully add a nice lowess smooth through these data points? 
When the span is at 0.5, warning are generated that say

```
  all data on boundary of neighborhood. make span bigger
```

But even setting the span at 1, you don't get a span, but some of the data points are connected with lines.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38864458/loess-warnings-errors-related-to-span-in-r) question suggests it is because the x-axis data has multiple entries for some points, and that does happen here. It suggests adding some jitter to the data. I did that with `geom_jitter()` (not included in code below) but that didn't solve the problem. I also tried using a sequence of numbers as the x-axis values, instead of the date and that did not work either.

Reproducible code follows below.

Thank you for any insights.

````
myfile<-'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sjkiss/NDP/master/Data/membership_data_NDP.csv'
members<-read.csv(myfile, colClasses=c('Date', 'numeric','numeric', 'numeric', 'numeric', 'numeric','numeric', 'Date', 'character'))

theme_set(theme_bw())
members %>% 
  select(population, votes_previous_election, seats_previous_election, members, date, recent_election) %>% 
  mutate(., members_per_capita=members/population, members_votes=members/votes_previous_election, members_seats=members/seats_previous_election) %>% 
  rename(., `Members\nper_capita`=members_per_capita, `Members\nper_vote`=members_votes, `Members\nper_seat`=members_seats) %>%
  gather(Variable, Value, 7:9) %>% 
  ggplot(., aes(x=date, y=Value, group=recent_election))+geom_point(aes(col=factor(recent_election)))+scale_color_discrete(name = "Recent Election")+scale_x_date() +facet_wrap(~Variable, scales='free')+geom_smooth(method='loess', span=0.5)
warnings()```
````

Comment: You have only one observation per group in each facet, I think it is complaining that it can't smooth from one data point.

Comment: If you want a single smoother per facet, take out the `group` aesthetic and use just `aes(x=date, y=Value)`.